# Batch Credit Card Processing

Tags: evaluating-civicrm, batches

Can CiviCRM do a batch credit card transactions where the transactions get send to the payment gateway in a batch?

I tried going to Contributions > Batch Data Entry / Accounting Batches, and when I create a new batch, I can select 'Credit Card' as a payment method against a contribution but there is no option to enter the credit card details.

Thanks for your help.